# Can lost wealth be restored by reciting the kaarta virya arjuna mantra?

Tags: mantras

I have had a theft at home and i was told that  reciting the *Kaartaviryaarjuna mantra* would help in restoring lost wealth (Jewels, Cash)

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer**: I guess no one can **Guarantee** that reciting of Kaartaviryaarjuna mantra would restore the lost wealth, it is more a question of **your** faith and belief.

Hence all I am doing here is trying to answer based on what is mentioned in stotra about Kartavirya Arjuna.

[Kartavirya Arjuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartavirya_Arjuna) was a legendary king of an ancient Haihayas kingdom with capital at Mahishamati. He is described as having a thousand hands and a great devotee of god Dattatreya.

First of all, in the very first stanza of [कार्तवीर्य द्वादशनामस्तोत्रम्](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/kArtavIrya12.html?lang=sa), below lines are mentioned:

> कार्तवीर्यार्जुनो नाम राजा बाहुसहस्रवान् । तस्य स्मरणमात्रेण गतं नष्टं
> च लभ्यते ॥ १॥

This loosly **translates** to something like "*the lost stuff is restored by remembering कार्तवीर्यार्जुनो नाम राजा*

Now, there is [one more version](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_vishhnu/kArtavIrya12.html?lang=sa) of कार्तवीर्य stotram containing his twelve
names, which also once agian mentions the same thing.

> द्वादशैतानि नामानि कार्तवीर्यस्य यः स्मरेत् ॥ २॥
>
> अनष्टद्रव्यता तस्य नष्टस्य पुनरागमः ।
>
> सम्पदस्तस्य जायन्ते जनास्तस्य वशो सदा ॥ ३॥

These verses say that one who remembers the twelve names of the great
Arjuna, son of Kritavirya, will be blessed with prosperity.
He will draw (attract) people to him. He will not lose his wealth or
property by theft etc., and will also get back the money that
he had lost.

Hence, there is mention of restoration of wealth, by reciting the name of Kritavirya Arjuna, but as I said before, it is more a question of your faith and belief. **It is then upto you to let us know if it worked for You!! Keep us posted**

Comment: I think there's no need to doubt this mantra. Any soulful proper recitation of authentic Sanskrit mantra will work.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Hmm...but I added that declaimer line for atheist who may be reading it. :)

Comment: @WhisperingMonk Ha, if by atheist you mean a person who doesn't believe in the power of this stotra, then (raises hands). Which Purana does this come in?

Comment: @Surya in the link that I posted in my post, Kartaviryarjuna is said to mentioned in Uttara Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana. (chapters 31 - 33) and also Srimad Bhagavatam says a few lines about Arjuna (he was the
son of Kritavirya and hence called Kartaviryarjuna), in verses 23 to 27 in
chapter 23, Book9. But if you mean where to find this stotram itself, then I have no idea...

Comment: @WhisperingMonk Yes, I meant the stotra.